# Is there a feature which has a combination of KendoMultiSelect control along with kendo MultiCalendar control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is there a feature which has a combination of KendoMultiSelect control along with KendoMultiCalendar control?

[image: multiselect with calendar]

Comment: There is no such feature out of the box, you would need to code it yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing from Telerik, but this project might be what you want.
https://github.com/iyegoroff/kendo-multi-date-select

For an example project take a look here: https://dojo.telerik.com/ereno/2

Comment: How would i get the source code for this plugin? Because we are not allowed to use plugins.

Comment: You could just copy the source of the JavaScript files (https://kendo-multi-calendar.surge.sh/kendo-multi-calendar.min.js, https://kendo-multi-date-select.surge.sh/kendo-multi-date-select.min.js). Well, and you should also put the license (https://github.com/iyegoroff/kendo-multi-date-select/blob/master/LICENSE) on top of them.